# WebGL 1D texture - shader value catch

Tags: arrays, textures, webgl, fragment-shader, computation

So I'm working on computation using GPU shaders in WebGL-
In the javascript portion of the code, I put precalculated values onto an array to send as a texture to be read up in the fragment shader-

```
        var count=0;
        var table = [];
        for (var y = 0.1; y<1; y+=.01) {

            for (var x = 0.1; x<1; x+=.01) {

                var u = x;
                var u2 = y;
                u += u2 * 0.003921568627451;
                u *= 4.0;
                var sig = 1/(Math.exp(2.0 *(u-3)) + 1);

                table.push(Math.floor(sig*255));
                //table.push(255);
                table.push(0);
                table.push(0);
                table.push(0);
                count+=4;


                console.log(Math.floor(sig*255)+"");
                console.log(0+"");
                console.log(0+"");
                console.log(0+"");


            }

        }

        //alert(count);
          //alert(table[101]);

        texturetab = gl.createTexture();

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturetab);

        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 100, 100, 0,

                      gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(table));

        //

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);



        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "uTabSamp"), 2);
```

but when I "catch" the values of the texture on the shader, the computation acts as if it is only reading values of 0- it's not changing as it should-
(Snippet of where the value is caught on the fragment shader) :

```
        sigmoid =  (texture2D(uTabSamp, vec2(floor(u*100.+.5), floor(u2*100.+.5))).r)/255.;

        float hfunc   = sigmoid * u * u;
        float ffunc   = -u +(a - pow(v*nb,m))*hfunc ;
```

Seeing as how WebGL is difficult to read, how do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

> texture2D(uTabSamp, vec2(floor(u*100.+.5), floor(u2*100.+.5))

Texture sample coordinates must range from 0.0 to 1.0. So scale your lookup for the texture size you built.

Your texture-making code isn't shown, but, be sure to set the interpolation to NEAREST (assuming you want exact access to the values), and sample from the "middle" of each pixel. For example, the bottom-left pixel from a 128 x 32 texture will be found at `vec2(0.5 / 128.0, 0.5 / 32.0)`.

Comment: gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Like so?